# Open android app and run it through command line

Tags: android

I want to open and run android app through command line.
Using this command, I can just open the app but I still cannot run it.

`adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName`

To run the app, I need to press start button after opening it, so how to specify that as well through adb?